# OpaqueToken is not a constructor

Tags: angular, localization, multilingual

I am trying to create a multilingual website using angular2 from the source code https://embed.plnkr.co/BnCRsCfB1ZIMoQ4QT6Lg/ but it is throwing error that

> opaqueToken is not a constructor.

Can anyone help me with this?

I have attached my package.json. Please find it below

`

```
{


"name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.19",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}

`
```

Comment: could you share your package.json?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your providers to a module.

This plunker has a good example of how to use: https://plnkr.co/edit/SHfTH9R6JVDwJKnzRFSH?p=preview

e.g.

App module - add providers here so each module can set what they need. The loggerapiconfig is the opaque token so the value can be set.

```
import { NgModule, provide } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmailModule, apiConfig as emailApiConfig } from './email/index';
import { LoggerModule, apiConfig as loggerApiConfig } from './logger/index';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    EmailModule,
    LoggerModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: emailApiConfig, useValue: { apiKey: 'email-key', context: 'registration' } },
    { provide: loggerApiConfig, useValue: { apiKey: 'logger-key' } },
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Logger Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { LoggerService } from './logger.service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [ LoggerService ],
})
export class LoggerModule { }
```

Logger Service - injects the opaquetoken with the values set in appmodule

```
import { Injectable, Inject, OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

import { LoggerConfig } from './logger.config';

export const apiConfig = new OpaqueToken('api-config');

@Injectable()
export class LoggerService {
  constructor(@Inject(apiConfig) public apiConfig: LoggerConfig) { }
}
```

Logger Config

```
export type LoggerConfig = {
  apiKey: string
}
```

logger/index

```
export { LoggerConfig } from './logger.config';
export { LoggerModule } from './logger.module';
export { apiConfig, LoggerService } from './logger.service';
```

**NOTE**

OpaqueToken is deprecated in newer versions of Angular. You will need to use the InjectionToken class https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken